# RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:BLOCK_TYPE_IS_NOT_01 error in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

im getting some error codes when i try to open my secured https spring boot app. I have generated a csr with a private key, signed the csr from an authority and saved the certificate with private key in a p

Error: write EPROTO 2008320520:error:0400006b:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:BLOCK_TYPE_IS_NOT_01:../../third_party/boringssl/src/crypto/fipsmodule/rsa/padding.c:108: 2008320520:error:04000088:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:PADDING_CHECK_FAILED:../../third_party/boringssl/src/crypto/fipsmodule/rsa/rsa_impl.c:673: 2008320520:error:10000072:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_SIGNATURE:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake_client.cc:1094:

Answer (score 0):

For future searches, the certificate is different of the generated.

In our case, we were using the mitmproxy for functional tests and running the mitmproxy with different user that generated the certificate, then the name and domain is correct, but using different certificates.